# Fazendo consulta no banco através de formulário utilizando django

Tags: python, django

Estou iniciando os estudos na utilização do framework django e estou tentando fazer consultas no banco utilizando um form para retornar um valor específico no banco.
Segue meu template:

```
<form method="GET"> 
{% csrf_token %} 
    <div class="card-body"> 
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">Preencha os dados para pesquisar os dados!</h3>
        <input class="input col-md-12" type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="11" style="margin: 4% 0% 2% 0%;">
        <button>Pesquisar</button>
    </div> 
</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>RESULTADO</th>
    </tr> 
{% for results in result %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{ results }}</td>
    </tr> 
{% endfor %} 
</table>
```

Segue minha view:

```
def consulta(request):
cpf = request.GET('cpf')
result = Login.objetos.filter(cpf)
return render(request, 'pesquisa.html',{'result': result})
```

Quando preencho o form e clico para pesquisar a página recarrega mas não retorna o resultado da consulta.

Comment: No seu template esta faltando o for para inserir o conteudo do result

Comment: Estava fazendo outras alterações para tentar fazer funcionar e coloquei o form no template, ele ficou assim agora:

Comment: <form method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 style="text-align:center;">Preencha os dados para pesquisar os dados!</h3>
            <input class="input col-md-12" type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="11" style="margin: 4% 0% 2% 0%;">
            <button>Pesquisar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>RESULTADO</th>
        </tr>
        {% for results in result %}
            <tr>
               <td>{{ results }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

Comment: não retorna nada? dentro da view tente dar um print no result para ver se está restornando algo do banco de dados

Comment: Não retorna, coloquei o print dentro da view, mas não imprime nada, pelo console eu vejo que está indo o conteúdo digitado no input, porém, não vem nenhum retorno

Comment: Ja experimentou ver se tem dados dentro da variável cpf ? se está no formato certo ao consultar na tela de login

Comment: Por padrão o requests.GET retorna none caso tenha algum problema(não encontre a key )

Comment: Não sei se existe outra forma, mas pelo terminal eu vejo que a variável recebe os dados, o estranho é que o GET não retorna none ou null.

Comment: Você deve corrigir objetos com objects.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que essa linha:

```
result = Login.objetos.filter(cpf)
```

não está correta, você deve apontar qual campo ou atributo do seu model que deve ser igual ao valor da variável CPF.

```
result = Login.objetos.filter(<nome_atributo_model>=cpf)
```

Não me lembro de ter visto a função .filter() sendo usada da maneira que você usou.

Comment: Tentei colocar dessa maneira, mas não tive retorno. Pelo os exemplos que vi na net no form não é definido nenhuma action para apontar pra uma página ou url específica, ai fico confuso se a url está acessando a função dentro da view ou não

Comment: a url que carrega o HTML que você informou está apontando para a função que você criou?

Comment: Não sei te dizer, como estou iniciando agora nos estudos ainda fico meio perdido. Como não defino nenhuma action no form fica difícil afirmar se a função está sendo chamada.